# Get a value from JSON data

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I have this Json data need to get the values on vb.net

```
{
    "type": "push",
    "targets": ["stream"],
    "push": {
        "type": "mirror",
        "source_device_iden": "ujzp6Xr9A4asjyjskXPzu8",
        "source_user_iden": "ujzp6Xr9A4a",
        "client_version": 354,
        "dismissible": true,
        "icon": "ok",
        "title": "test",
        "body": "Hi",
        "application_name": "WhatsApp",
        "package_name": "com.whatsapp",
        "notification_id": "1",
        "notification_tag": "y9x5Q2YAI\/pqPhZwbaN6TpoW4eJhe0kAe0HfmWOQyWA=\n",
        "conversation_iden": "{\"package_name\":\"com.whatsapp\",\"tag\":\"y9x5Q2YAI\\\/pqPhZwbaN6TpoW4eJhe0kAe0HfmWOQyWA=\\n\",\"id\":1}"
    }
}
```

### I tried this code it is return error

```
 Dim json As String = TextBox1.Text
      Dim ser As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
        Dim data As List(Of JToken) = ser.Children().ToList

        For Each item As JProperty In data
            item.CreateReader()
            Select Case item.Name

                Case "push"
                    For Each msg As JObject In item.Value

                        Dim tyep As String = msg("type")
                        Dim source As String = msg("source_device_iden")

                    Next
            End Select


        Next
```

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty' to type
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.'

Comment: You have a string representing a JSON object as the value of a Property (`conversation_iden`) that looks like it has been pasted in formatted from the IDE. Are you sure this is the actual JSON or is it your *elaboration*? `notification_tag` contains what could be a Base64 encoded string terminated with a `\n`. Where does the `\n` come from?

Comment: `"icon": test` is wrong, not double quotes. I doubt this is the actual JSON.

Comment: Just [edit] your question, do not try to fix it adding comments

Comment: which line of code throws the error exactly? If it's this line: `For Each msg As JObject In item.Value` then you need to tell us which item of data causes the crash. use your debugger to step through the code until it crashes and examine the variables so you can see which item in the list is currently being processed at that time. I'm going to guess it's maybe `conversation_iden` (since that property unhelpfully contains double-encoded JSON for some reason) but it would be useful for you to confirm it.

Comment: For Each msg As JObject In item.Value

Comment: Ok. So in that case please review the rest of my comment and provide the necessary information so that we can proceed. Thankyou.

Answer (score -1):

```
   Dim json As String = TextBox1.Text
              Dim ser As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
                Dim data As List(Of JToken) = ser.Children().ToList

                For Each item As JProperty In data
                    item.CreateReader()
                    Select Case item.Name

                        Case "push"
                            For Each msg As JObject In item
        Dim tyep As String = msg("type")
                                Dim source As String = msg("source_device_iden")

                            Next
                    End Select


                Next
```

Comment: Is this your solution? Or an attempt to add more information to your question? It's unclear, especially since you didn't add any kind of explanation

Comment: issue was with this line  :  old << For Each msg As JObject In item.Value >>  new << For Each msg As JObject In item >>